# Return multiple rows from database in node

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to return all the details of the product and display them in table format

I have already tried this in my api

```
app.get('/test',(req,res) => {
const client = new Client({
    connectionString: connectionString
})
client.connect()
client.query('select * from product',(err,res) =>{
    console.log(err,res)
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }else{
        console.log(res);


    }
    client.end()
})})
```

How do i return this res in node?

Answer (score 0):

You are hiding the outside res in the route handler with the inside res of the query result.

I have to make some assumptions about your query client, but if the inside res is the array of rows, simply pass it to the res.json() function (another assumption is you are using Express).

My suggestion:

```
app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
    const client = new Client({
        connectionString: connectionString
    })
    client.connect()
    client.query('select * from product', (err, rows) => {
        console.log(err, rows)
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log(rows);

            res.json(rows);

        }
        client.end()
    })
});
```